# ASP.NET MVC: new session occasionally created when returning from payment provider

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, session, cookies

Running .net 4.6.1 and MVC 5 using the built in [authentication](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=301864) (OWIN) and Identity I am having a problem with sessions occasionally not being preserved when returning from the third party payment provider.

I have spent some days on this reading, searching and testing, but although I see similar problems storing a session variable and then redirecting, those were all in older versions and I am not sure this is what is happening here. Furthermore it only happens about one in ten times and I have had it both fail and work in chrome so it is not browser specific.

There is a lot of code, but the relevant parts look like this:

```
[HttpPost]
public async Task<ActionResult> CreateUser(Model model)    
{
    // store number so I can find user later
    Session["mobilenumber"] = model.mobile;
    // create user (skipping code for populating user and password from model)
    var result = await UserManager.CreateAsync(user, password);
    if (result.Succeeeded)
    {
        await SignInManager.SignInAsync(user, isPersistent: false, rememberBrowser: false); // TODO: persist and remember false?

        Redirect("https://paymentprovider.com");
    }
}
```

When returning I try to read the session:

```
string mobileNumber = (Session["mobilenumber"] ?? String.Empty).ToString();
```

I log the session ID and Session_Start and Session_End, and the log looks like this when it fails:

```
Time    Thread  Details
09:15:58    34  Error retrieving session details since those were stored in session ntzwxal2iryodl40pmjtp5re
09:15:58    34  User returns from payment provider and new session is started, Session_Start: xcgxslnc0qblcry0crjwoykp
09:14:59    41  Create, sign in and redirect user to payment provider (store user in sessionID: ntzwxal2iryodl40pmjtp5re)
09:13:20    41  Session_Start: ntzwxal2iryodl40pmjtp5re
```

I am at my wits end trying to figure out why it randomly uses a new session at times. Seems it must be a problem with the cookie, but note from the log above that the session was started long before the redirect, so I suspect that the problem is something else. I don't think the thread it runs on is interesting and haven't seen a pattern there, but include it anyway.

Note that most of the time it does work and gets the same session, but suddenly when testing I get this. This is in release running on IIS server.

Also not that I considered going cookieless, but that does not work with how the code is written, is not secure with authentication from what I read and creates ugly urls. So I'm stuck with cookies.

Note that User.Identity.GetUserId() also fails, which I think again just shows that the session is lost.

Comment: I think it has something to do with IIS recycling application pool. Do you think the cases where you are facing the issue exceeds the "idle timeout" property, which is by default 20 minutes? Application pool also gets recycled at every 29 hours (set by "Regular Timeout" property in IIS irrespective to being idle or not.

Comment: That was my first suspect, but no the timeout is 20 minutes and as you can see from the above log Session_End is not called. I can see sessions being recycled roughly every 20 minutes, unless I keep using the session. Then it doesn't get recyled strangely enough. Also curiously I noted that when I resumed activity after a session had ended (Session_End) a new session (Session_Start) was begun with exactly the same session ID as I had on my previous session.

Comment: Another remote possibility is that the session problem has something to do with the authentication. The action the payment provider returns to requires the user was signed in inside the action before redirecting to the payment provide. This is handled with [Authorize] annotation.